# OpenSSL CFB Modes

Tags: encryption, openssl

I'm trying to understand OpenSSL notation - what is the difference between, for example:

```
AES-256-CFB
```

and

```
AES-256-CFB1
AES-256-CFB8
```

I get the `CFB1` and `CFB8` difference, but really can't find to which category I should assign `CFB`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please don’t get me wrong, but I’m not really sure why the question arises as it should be pretty clear when you’ve checked the manual.

Quoting the information available online at https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-enc.html

```
…
aes-[128|192|256]-cfb  = 128/192/256 bit AES in 128 bit CFB mode
aes-[128|192|256]-cfb1 = 128/192/256 bit AES in 1 bit CFB mode
aes-[128|192|256]-cfb8 = 128/192/256 bit AES in 8 bit CFB mode
…
```

So, the difference is that – in contrast to `cfb` which uses 128 bit CFB mode by default – the other options (`cfb1` and `cfb8`) handle things  bit- and byte-wise accordingly… `cfb1` handles things *bit-wise* and `cfb8` handles things *byte-wise*.

Simpler stated: generally, when looking at OpenSSL commandline parameters et al, the `1` or `8` at the end of some of the encryption modes specifies ***the number of bits used in [cipher feedback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Feedback_.28CFB.29)***. As the quoted manual excerpt clearly states, the `aes-[128|192|256]-cfb` uses `128 bit CFB mode`.

> I get the CFB1 and CFB8 difference, but really can't find to which category I should assign CFB.

Maybe it helps to *“categorize”* it if you simply think of `cfb` without numeric ending as (let’s just call it) *“default”*… or *“the way OpenSLL assumes things to be handled by default, unless stated otherwise”*.

aes-[128|192|256]-cfb = default,
aes-[128|192|256]-cfb1 = alternate option, using 1 bit instead of 128 bits,
aes-[128|192|256]-cfb8 = alternate option, using 8 bits instead of 128 bits.

As you can see, it’s practically the same as what the manual states.

Comment: Well, I expected to find such info under _crypto library_ and not _commands_ page. Anyway, it's good to know that default is 128 bit.

Comment: @otus The question was migrated to SuperUser as mikeazo and I both regarded this to be a “it’s in the manual” kind of thing which practically pointed to (what the crypto.se help center describes as) “use of software, not its cryptographic internals”… aka *off-topic at crypto.se*. Now, I’m not saying that things should always stay that way, but it’s what the crypto.se help center currently states. If you feel it could make sense to change the rules, I can only point to crypto.meta where you could throw in an according question/discussion. Who knows? General consensus might be open for a change.

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs Glad I could help… ;)

Comment: `dpkg -L openssl | fgrep /man/ | fgrep .gz | wc -l` gives 55, so RTFM leaves you with a 1 of 55 (less than 2%) chance to accidentally hit the right manpage.  Hence I wouldn't say **the manual**, I'd rather say "the information you need is **well hidden at the end of `man enc`**!"